# Unable to access all ItemResponses in a FormResponse

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a strange error occurring in an Apps Script function attached to a Google Form.

I call the responses, then list them in an array. The log shows that there are 6 items in the array, which matches the six form questions:

```
[18-05-08 00:13:31:900 AEST] [ItemResponse, ItemResponse, ItemResponse, ItemResponse, ItemResponse, ItemResponse]
```

When I call the first two, it works just fine. Any more and it bugs out and says `undefined`.

```
// Open a form by ID and log the responses to each question.
var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
var formResponses = form.getResponses();
for (var i = 0; i < formResponses.length; i++) {
  var formResponse = formResponses[i];
  var editUrl = String(formResponse.getEditResponseUrl());
  var theResponseId = formResponses.indexOf(form);
  var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
  var timestamp = formResponse.getTimestamp();  
  var firstName = itemResponses[0].getResponse();
  var lastName = itemResponses[1].getResponse();
  Logger.log(itemResponses); // Log shows there are 6 objects in the array. Matching the amount of Form Questions.

  // If I try to use these variables below, it doesn't work and the script 'breaks' at this point.

  //var number = itemResponses[2].getResponse();
  //var email = itemResponses[3].getResponse();
  //var firstName2 = itemResponses[4].getResponse();
  //var comments = itemResponses[5].getResponse();
}
```

**Note:** I have tried `FormApp.openById('id');` to see if maybe getting the active form was a problem. This didn't help.

Comment: @tehhowch thank you for always being here to guide me. I have updated with logs

Comment: And the actual full error you are getting? Per [documentation for `ItemResponse`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item-response) I don't see any issue.

Comment: @tehhowch TypeError: Cannot call method "getResponse" of undefined. (line 15, file "Code") - That's if I try to add one of the additional variables

Comment: This simply shows that the answer was submitted to a 2 question form. Are you sure your form consists of 6 questions?

Comment: @AntonDementiev The form originally had two questions. I did submit some responses while it was this way. It now definitely has 6 questions.

Comment: If you submitted some responses prior to extending the from, the answers to these new questions will most certainly be "undefined" for older responses

Comment: @AntonDementiev I thought of that as I answered your last question. Thank you so much. I have submitted an answer, but I don't know the 'ethical' thing to do. Should you submit the answer so I can tick it off?

Comment: No worries - glad I could help. I posted the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because some answers were submitted to a 2 question form. If you submitted some responses prior to updating the form, the answers to these new questions will be "undefined".

Comment: I'm having one more related issue even with the fix. If I submit a form, and only have half the form filled out on submit. It actually breaks the script and reduces the array for future use. Would you know why this is happening?

Comment: ----------------- FIXED ----------------- If I called .getResponse and the itemResponses variable was undefined, it caused an error. So I made an if statement for each variable that looked like this -> if(itemResponses[3] != undefined){ var email = itemResponses[3].getResponse; };

Comment: In a loop, you can replace that with if ( itemResponses[j] ) { // do something }. It checks for null, undefined, empty string (""), etc.